# How to speed up Python execution?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have a project written in Python which work with a big size of data.
I would like to speed up the execution time.

In simple words, let's say I have this sample fully optimized code:

```
def foo(x):
   doSomething

main():
   for i in range(1,10000000):
      foo(i)
```

Is there some way to speed up this? For example by using multiprocessing or other stuff?
And most important, is it worth?

Thanks for replies. I think I will try the route of multiprocessing. Someone can suggest me a guide or some example for helping me?

Comment: You should really use `xrange` instead of `range` - otherwise you put all the "data" in memory just to iterate over it.

Comment: Holds onlx for 2.x, not 3.x...

Answer (score 9):

To answer your last question first, if you have a problem with performance, then it's worth it. That's the only criterion, really.

As for how:

If your algorithm is slow because it's computationally expensive, consider rewriting it as a [C extension](http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html#extending-index), or use [Cython](http://cython.org/), which will let you write fast extensions in a Python-esque language. Also, [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) is getting faster and faster and may just be able to run your code without modification.

If the code is not computationally expensive, but it just loops a huge amount, it may be possible to break it down with Multiprocessing, so it gets done in parallel.

Lastly, if this is some kind of basic data splatting task, consider using a fast data store. All the major relational databases are optimised up the wazoo, and you may find that your task can be sped up simply by getting the database to do it for you. You may even be able to shape it to fit a [Redis](http://redis.io/) store, which can aggregate big data sets brilliantly.

Answer (score 7):

The only *real* way to know would be to profile and measure. Your code could be doing anything. "doSomething" might be a `time.sleep(10)` in which case, forking off `10000000` processes would make the whole program run in approximately 10 seconds (ignoring the forking overhead and resulting slowdowns).

Use http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html and check to see where the bottle necks are, see if you can optimise the "fully optimised" program using better coding. If it's already fast enough, stop.

Then, depending on whether it's CPU or I/O bound and the hardware you have, you might want to try multiprocessing or threading. You can also try distributing to multiple machines and doing some map/reduce kind of thing if your problem can be broken down.

Comment: Ok thanks for reply. Well, my program just loops a huge amount of data so I don't think that more optimisation would increase so much the performance. 

So my question would be: using multiprocessing how much speed would I gain? 
Consider that my project can be summarized as a loop in an array of a million cells.
Sorry for bad english..:)

Comment: Well, you can split it into 100 equal sized pieces and use a worker pool to process each piece and then join the results.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) interpreter which has a JIT compiler built into it, it might actually improve performance over loops like this. Here is a [link](http://speed.pypy.org/) that explains some of the speed ups that the PyPy interpreter offers over regular CPython.

Or you could write your code using [Cython](http://cython.org/) which allows native c extensions inside python. Huge chunks of numpy are written this way to get good speed ups.

Or you could forget using python and just write it in ASM. Sure it will be harder to do but when you see that your program runs ~1% faster than everyone elses? You will be happy you went that extra mile.

Comment: +1 for mentioning PyPy. Also, I'm quite sure that rewriting it in assembly will give you more than a 1% boost. :)

Comment: Yea but anyone that is that anal about optimisation can go sit in the corner with the glitter and safety glue.

Comment: It *is* possible to go the other way as well.

Answer (score -1):

If the tasks can be worked upon in parallel, you could investigate in using a process pool using the `multiprocessing` module and have the jobs distributed among the subprocesses.

Answer (score -1):

Function call also has overhead, try putting loop into function:

```
def foo(x):
   for i in range(1,x):
      doSomething

main():
   foo(10000000)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).